# django remote development server doesn't reload py file

Tags: python, django

I'm running django development server remotely using

```sh
python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000
```

The project is available through Dropbox. I make the changes locally in my system and they are available to my testers when I checkin code to Dropbox folder.

The problem I'm facing is that the development server does not reload the code automatically. It somehow keeps running the same old code.

The development server on the same machine run on `127.0.0.1:8001` behaves as expected.

Is there a way to force reloading of files when django development server is run remotely?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try using `git` instead of dropbox and in your server only do `git pull`and restart the server.

Comment: I'm using git for versioning. Dropbox is just used to auto-deploy the changes. Shouldn't django auto-reload the changed files without restart?

Comment: Depends on the files and where they are. If they're in packages in your site packages folder, it won't.

Comment: Well, these are py files in my apps, urls.py. Even when I restart the server, these are not picked up. Any idea why?

Comment: I found the problem. One of my peers rdp to the remote system under different login, and started the server. There was problem of multiple instances running on the same port; which caused the above mentioned issue. Is there a way to stop reusing the same port for development server?

I hope this answer might someone else visiting this page.

Thanks to all who tried to answer my concern.